# EF, MVC, Model binding, and Navigation properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-binding

I'm using EF5 Code First with :

```
public class Scenario
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public  IList<Client> Clients { get; set; }
}
public class Client
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int VisibilityNumber{ get; set; }
}
```

I'm directly sending the scenario object to the view (MVC4, without using a viewmodel class - maybe a mistake ?, but a lot less plumbing code). In my view, I use HiddenFor for Scenario.Id, and a for loop to display an EditFor for each client VisibilityNumber.

This is the Controller :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection formValues)
{     
if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Scenario scen=GetScenarioFromDB(id);
        TryUpdateModel(scen,formValues);
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
           SaveToDb(scen);
    }
}
```

After the TryUpdateModel, for each Clients object (which were correctly loaded from DB) :

- VisibilityNumber is correctly set
- Id is set to 0, which of course is a bad thing
- Name is set to null

After looking at the MVC Source code (DefaultModelBinder/UpdateCollection), I can see that when binding to collections, new items are always created.
If I can't fix that, I think I'm going to use a viewModel, and AutoMapper. I assume that the MVC team wanted to force us to use viewModel, rather than directly send EF object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I "fixed" DefaultModelBinder/UpdateCollection so that it can work with my use case : when the binding is drilling down in the navigation properties, it uses the current object as model (it's easy, since I'm only doing modifications, no insert or delete) : I can take the DefaultModel source code, put my fix in it, and use it as a custom model binder. It's fun, but a bit dirty and over the top.
2. But I believe the best way is to use a specific ViewModel, using only the properties which are editable, and use AutoMap to map it to my EF hierarchy. BUT : it has the same problem of creating child objects collection.
3. In the end, I just did some manual mapping for between my View Model and my EF hierarchy : I'm nearly sure I can do something automatic, which could detect if a child item has been modified or inserted or deleted  (since every item has a [key] property, but I just don't have the time budget to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

You should not get `scenario` from database in your update. Instead, you should take your bound model, attach it (if edited) or add it (if new) to context and then save changes. It's a common scenario called "disconnected entities" (which you, in fact, do have, because you have model that was disconnected when sent to client, and then got back also disconnected).

Comment: I can't do that, because my bound model does not contains all my database fields.
For example, the Name property is only displayed on the view, so it's not in the bound model. 
I know I could fix that using Hidden Field, but it just seems wrong. UpdateModel is made for my scenario (and works as long as I don't have navigation properties)

Comment: @Guillaume That is also covered by same use case. You'll just need to explicitly mark appropriate properties as changed.

Comment: Ok ! I just don't see how I can do that without mixing too much my web and data layer : currently, my MVC project does not know about the datacontext. I also don't want to make web specific methods in my data layer (to tell which "appropriate properties" have changed). Thanks anyway

Comment: @Guillaume your web and data layer began being too much mixed at the moment you decided to directly use data model in web layer.

Comment: I'm using code first, regular POCOs with only a few Annotations, so I'm not sure this could be considered as a data model.
The only data model intrusions are some of the annotations, which I could move farther by going the fluent route.

Comment: @Guillaume while it is not, speaking strictly, a *data* model (more along the route of *domain* model), it's still not a *presentation* (view) model.